# Run doc test in examples/ folder with cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to execute Rust's [documentation tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html) written in the `examples/` folder.

````rust
// examples/example.rs

//! ```rust
//! panic!();
//! ```

fn main() {}
````

I would expect `cargo test --doc` to panic, but the above documentation test is never run. When I define the same documentation test in `src/lib.rs` `cargo test --doc` panics as expected.

How do I run a documentation test which is defined in the `examples/` folder?

Environment:

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.51.0 (43b129a20 2021-03-16)
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.51.0 (2fd73fabe 2021-03-23)
```

Comment: 1. `cargo doc` and `cargo test` will not include unused files, which for some reason includes examples. 2. I'm not sure if you know but examples/ is a special category, which has some functionalities, e.g. all the files in it are compiled (but not run) when running `cargo test` and an example can be run with `cargo run --example [name]` 3. `cargo doc` probably doesn't generate documentation for examples because it doesn't know what to do with it (e.g. where on the page to put it)

Comment: > 3. cargo doc probably doesn't generate documentation for examples because it doesn't know what to do with it (e.g. where on the page to put it)

It does generate documentation for examples when adding the below to ones `Cargo.toml`, though, as you said, the generated docs are not referenced in the original crate, nor are the documentation tests executed.

```
\[\[example]]
name = "example"
doc = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation tests in Rust are only run for modules that are used in your library when built for `cfg(doc)`. Also `doctest = true` in `Cargo.toml` is currently (Rust 1.51) [unsupported for example sections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#the-doctest-field).

One reason for this is that documentation tests are run as if they were executables that link to your library. For documentation tests on examples it is not clear how they should run. An executable linking to an example executable doesn't make much sense.

But there is a hacky workaround:

You can use the attribute [`path="…"`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute) to include the examples as modules in your library (e.g. in `src/lib.rs`) and combine this with the conditional compilation attribute [`cfg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) and [`doc(hidden)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/the-doc-attribute.html#dochidden) to only do this when generating documentation while not producing output for these modules in the result:

```rust
#[cfg(doc)]
#[doc(hidden)]
#[path = "../examples"]
mod examples {
    mod example;
}
```

This causes documentation tests in `examples/example.rs` to be included when running `cargo test --doc`. If you want to import something from `example.rs` in your doctest you need to access the namespace using `your_library::examples::example::…` and add `pub` to the module declarations.

```
$ cargo test --doc
…
test src/../examples/example.rs - examples::example (line 2) ... FAILED

failures:

---- src/../examples/example.rs - examples::example (line 2) stdout ----
Test executable failed (exit code 101).

stderr:
thread 'main' panicked at 'explicit panic', src/../examples/example.rs:3:1
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```